# How to make Mercurial on Windows use an SSH key for push/pull?

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

How to tell TortoiseHg (or Mercurial in general) that I want to use a given SSH key when pushing/pulling to/from a remote repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, see [Accessing SSH-controlled repositories from a Windows client](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AccessingSshRepositoriesFromWindows): you need PuTTY, plink and a particular config setting.

To put that in a particular repository, put in `.hg/hgrc`

```
[ui]
ssh="C:\path to\plink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\your path to\private.key"
```

Also note that you don't need to specify the key path if you use pageant.

Comment: I just want to add to this great answer that, if you added to the `ssh://` url of the repo an username and you login to the machine with another username, you have to add `-l $login_username`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PuTTY, set up a profile in that for the connection to the remote repository.  and then in TortoiseHg you can then connect to ssh://profilename/

e.g. I set one up for bitbucket and called it bitb, so the connection is
ssh://bitb/url-to-repo.